# How can I get this regexp working?

Tags: regex, perl

Should be easy, but this regexp is not working (Perl):

```
^(.*?)-(.*?)(-(.*)|$)
```

## match

a - b - c  (I want $1=a, $2=b, $3=c)
a - b      (I want $1=a, $2=b)

## !match

abc

Any ideas welcome.
You can try it here:
https://regex101.com/r/kP0fN9/2

Comment: Could you at least state what you want?

Comment: Did you try: `/^[^-]+(-[^-]+)*$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^[^-]*-(?:[^-]*-)?[^-]*$
```

OR

```
^[^-\n]*-(?:[^-\n]*-)?[^-\n]*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qU7nN0/1)

Update:

```
^(.*?)\s*-\s*(.*?)\s*(?:-\s*(.*)|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kP0fN9/3)

Comment: Add `\n` character inside the character class if the input contains  multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks for our reply.
I have updated my question to clarify, it was unclear when you gave this reply.

Comment: @user77115 did you want to match also `abc`?

Comment: No. I want to extract data from loglines on the format:
"a - b - c"
or
"a - b"

Comment: @user77115 i just modified your regex. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @res = $_ =~ /([^-]+)/g;
    dump@res;
}


__DATA__
a - b - c
a - b
```

**Output:**

```
("a ", " b ", " c")
("a ", " b")
```